# Angular ESBuild Configuration (e.g. --define)

Tags: angular, esbuild

As of Angular 17, it is possible to build and serve with esbuild instead of webpack [1](https://angular.io/guide/esbuild).
With webpack there was a way use a custom webpack config for things like:

- Providing browser polyfills for `process`, `path` and others
- Using defines for build time environment variables

Is it possible to do the same with esbuild? I know there is `--define:x=y` [2](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#define), but I don't see a way to configure it in the Angular builder (`@angular-devkit/build-angular:application`).

I also found [angular-cli#24163](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/24163) which was resolved by [angular-cli#26011](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/26011), but could not find a way to practically implement that.

Comment: @Huka No. So far the only workaround is to use Nx with the [`@nx/angular:application`](https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular/executors/application) executor and use esbuild plugins (.js files)

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to set variables with esbuild?

Comment: No, still not possible